# How to run NARDL in R for multiple variables?

Tags: r

**Non-linear ARDL model**

**Description of variables**

- log of Total financial Savings (lnTFS): the dependent variable
- Real Deposit Rates(RDR): the decomposed dependent variable in rdr_p and rdr_n
- log of Real GDP per capita(lnRGDP)
- Average per density bank(APDB)**

I managed to run this command:

`reg<-nardl(formula = TFS~RDR,data=Savings,ic="aic",maxlags=TRUE,graph=TRUE,case=3)`

Adding 2 more independednt variables (log(RGDP) and APDB):

`reg<-nardl(formula = TFS~RDR + log(RGDP)+APDB,data =Savings,ic="aic",maxlags=TRUE,graph=TRUE,case=3)`

gives me the error message:

**`Error in nardl(formula = TFS ~ RDR + log(RGDP) + APDB, data = Savings,  : 
  nardl package accept only one decomposed variable`**

which command can I use to run nardl with multiple variables?

This is quarterly data from 1995Q1

`dput(head(Savings))`

```
`structure(list(Date = c(1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 1996L
), TFS = c(827.9, 894.7, 817.4, 796.3, 830, 839.1), RGDP = c(0.0057, 
0.0058, 0.0062, 0.0064, 0.0058, 0.0064), RDR = c(-1.14, -1.2, 
-2.18, -2.42, -2.57, -2.16), APDB = c(0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 
0.003, 0.003)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`
```

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Hie Artem, I have edited my question. is it clearer now? Pardon me as I am using Stack overflow for the very first time.

Comment: It would be nice if you post some data you are referencing to, `Savings`. Please use `dput(head(Savings))` results into your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to decompose your independent variables in positive and negative effects and just use the ARDL package in R. Of course, I strongly recommend you to read the paper so you can take correct decisions with regard to F bounds and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use ' | ' to separate the decomposed variable from the explanatory variables. Your specification assumes the decomposed variable includes RDR, log(RGDP) and APDB and the NARDL model has only one. The right specification is:

```
reg<-nardl(formula = TFS ~ RDR | log(RGDP) + APDB,
data=Savings, ic="aic", maxlags=TRUE, graph=TRUE, case=3)
```

where RDR is the passed decomposed variable while other variable are explanatory.